# run multiple python files with the same socket

Tags: python, file, sockets, server

I'm trying to make an online "MS paint" with sockets. i proggramed 2 files, one for the app menu and log in and stuff, and one for the actual paint.
i connect to the server with these lines:

```
my_socket=socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
```

when the user wants to start painting, i want to open the paint file, and use the same socket he connected to in the menu, but i'm having trouble to do so.
how do i use the same socket in the other file?

Comment: This is quite unclear. Two programs can connect to the same listening port just fine (after all, that's how servers work). What do you mean with "use the same socket in the other file"?

Comment: i have 2 python files, that both need to send data to the server, and that the server will know they are from the same user. i need something that i can write that will connect the actions from both files to the same socket

Comment: You should probably show what you've written into your two files so far...